# Paypal IPN spontaneous connection fail

Tags: php, curl, nginx, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am having a sticky issue with PayPal IPN.
In short, sometimes it works flawlessly, sometimes it does not.

I am guessing that it is a spontaneous connection issue with PayPal servers and I  am planning to create a retry script, which will try to connect again after a few seconds in case of a failure and up to 3 tries.

However, I thought to also bring this here in case I am missing something.

The code I am using is directly through [PayPal Github](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/PaypalIPN.php):

The error I am getting is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'cURL error: [7] Failed to connect to ipnpb.paypal.com port 443: Connection refused' in /mysite/PaypalIPN.php:129\nStack trace:\n#0 /mysite/buy.php(11): PaypalIPN->verifyIPN()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /mysite/PaypalIPN.php on line 129
```

At buy.php (11) I have:

```
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
```

At PayPalIPN.php (129) (The PayPal script) I have:

```
$res = curl_exec($ch);
        if ( ! ($res)) {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            (Line 129) throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
```

Like I said, the very same script succeeds 90% of the time. The very last example includes 4 (delayed) IPNs sent in space of a few minutes. One registered successfully and the other 3 haven't.

I am using WHM/Cpanel with Engintron for nginx. This is my only other suspicion, if there is some issue with nginx. But it does not make sense to me that it works at one time and not at another.

Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: Updating OpenSSL and cURL fixed the issue.